# Problem playing sound on iPad device with MonoTouch

Tags: ios, resources, audio, xamarin.ios

I am using the following code to play a .CAF file in an iPad application via Monotouch:

```
        public void PlayClick()
        {
            PlaySound("Media/Click.caf");
        }

        private void PlaySound(string soundFile)
        {
            //var mediaFile = NSUrl.FromFilename(soundFile);
            //var audioPlayer = new SystemSound(mediaFile);
            //audioPlayer.PlaySystemSound();
            var audioPlayer = new SystemSound(soundFile);
            if (audioPlayer != null)
            {
               audioPlayer.PlaySystemSound();
            }
        }
```

It works find in the simulator - in fact, all variations I've tried (SystemSound, AVAudioPlayer, etc.) appear to work ok in the simulator, but I've not gotten a version to play on a real device yet.  The sound files are all marked as Content and I checked the bundle uploaded to the iPad and the files are definitely there in a subfolder named "Media".  If I change the code to use SystemSound (via the constructor with Url), I get an **InvalidOperationException** with the details:

**Could not create system sound ID for url file://localhost/private/var/mobile/Applications/AC24496E-12E9-4690-B154-BA1AD1123EDC/Sample.app/Media/Click.caf; error=SystemSoundUnspecified**

Anyone know what am I doing wrong?  Thanks for any pointers to get me past this issue!

Comment: Argh! The device file system is case sensitive.. the filename was actually named "click.caf" .. not "Click.caf".  Apparently the simulator isn't quite as picky!  Problem solved.. nothing to see here.. :-)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The simulator is case-aware, but the actual device is case-sensitive.  This has tripped up many people.